# How to mock class attributes using pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-mock

I have a class something like this.

```
class Upgrade:

    def __init__(self, ssh_client):
        self.ssh_client = ssh_client
        self.channel = self.ssh_client.invoke_shell(width=1000, height=1000)
        self.stdin = self.channel.makefile('wb')
        self.stdout = self.channel.makefile('r')


    def do_upgrade(self):

        # execute some commands on paramiko channel

        for line in self.stdout:
            
            if str(line).startswith("PLAY RECAP"):
                
                # do something
```

When I trying to mock self attribute called 'stdout' like this(using pytest),

```
def return_stdout(*args, **kwargs):
    stdout = "\n\rSome return value\n\r"
    return stdout
monkeypatch.setattr(Upgrade, 'stdout', return_stdout)
```

I'm getting following error.

```
>     monkeypatch.setattr(Upgrade, 'stdout', return_stdout)
E     AttributeError: <class 'Upgrade'> has no attribute 'stdout'
```

Then, How can I mock 'stdout' using pytest or pytest-mock?

Comment: the *class* does not have the attribute, you're setting `a` as an *instance* variable. If you want to mock it for the class, declare it there first (`class MyClass: \n a = None \n def __init__(...` , but then the constructor will override the value later on anyway. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually I need to test do_upgrade function.
class Upgrade:

    def __init__(self, ssh_client):
        self.ssh_client = ssh_client
        self.channel = self.ssh_client.invoke_shell(width=1000, height=1000)
        self.stdin = self.channel.makefile('wb')
        self.stdout = self.channel.makefile('r')

    def do_upgrade(self):
        for line in self.stdout:
                logging.info(str(line))
                if str(line).startswith("PLAY RECAP"):
                    # do something

Comment: please add the code to the original question where it can be formatted/highligted, not like this.

Comment: Question is updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the *class* does not have the attribute, you're setting `stdout` as an *instance* variable. And even if you'd mock it, you'd overwrite it in the constructor (`self.stdout = self.channel.makefile('r')`). Create a wrapper/property, and monkeypatch that instead:

```
class Upgrade:
    def __init__(self, ssh_client):
        self._stdout = self.channel.makefile('r')

    def get_stdout(self):
        return self._stdout
```

then in the test mock the encapsulating method instead:

```
monkeypatch.setattr(Upgrade, 'get_stdout', return_stdout)
```